# PHP adding Subarray from an array

Tags: php, arrays

This code is now working! (Thanks to all!).  It was suggested earlier by a user to not have the two loops.  Any advice for how to remove a loop and speed this up a bit?

```
foreach($deviceList2 as $key => $value)
        $items = []; // create a new array to store the items
            foreach($itemList2 as $item) {
                if ($item[hostid] == $host[hostid]) {
                    $items[] = $item; // push the item to the empty array
                }
            }
    $host[inspections] = $items; // update the items to the host
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data, an example is sometimes a lot easier to understand.

Comment: You don't need to use a reference for objects, only for arrays.

Comment: If you have a unique field in an array of objects, things become much easier if you make the array associative and use that as the key. Then you don't need nested loops to find the matching elements.

Comment: This code looks like it came verbatim from one of your answers yesterday. If that code isn't working, you should clarify that question rather than posting a new question that lacks the same context.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I am new to this functionality as well as the forums so I apologize for the repetitiveness.  What would the process look like for making the array associative, perhaps that could be my problem?

Comment: So I was able to make this work by the following, any advice on how to remove the loops?
  foreach($deviceList2 as &$host) { // set the host as reference foreach($deviceList2 as $key => $value)
         $items = []; // create a new array to store the items
       foreach($itemList2 as $item) {
           if ($item[hostid] == $host[hostid]) {
               $items[] = $item; // push the item to the empty array
           }
       }
     $host[inspections] = $items; // update the items to the host
}

Comment: @LennyConvis, your last comment is not very readable. You can either update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Reposted with the edited code :-)

Comment: If `hostid` and `inspections` are constants, you should write them in all uppercase. If they aren't, you should wrap them in single quotes: `$host['hostid']`.